# JS-switchery sends two ajax request instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am using js-switchery to customize my checkbox. `onchage` the checkbox perform ajax request to the controller and thats how i am making the product(let's say) active or unactive. But now my checkbox sends two request each time when i change it and in result i can't change the state of my product(active or unactive).
AJAX:

```
function changeStatusActive(id, controllerName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/admin/' + controllerName + '/changestatusactive',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
        }
    });
}
```

Controller action:

```
public function actionChangestatusactive() {
        if (isset($_POST['id']) and ! empty($_POST['id'])) {
            $model = Product::findOne((int) $_POST['id']);
            if ($model) {
                if ($model->active == 1) {
                    $model->active = 2;
                } else {
                    $model->active = 1;
                }
                $model->update();
            }
        }
    }
```

My model function :

```
public function changeActiveForm() {
        $active = "";
        if ($this->active == 1) {
            $active = 'checked="checked"';
        }
        return '<label class="switchery switchery-default taCenter">
                <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" value="1" id="check_' . $this->id . '" name="field_types" ' . $active . ' onchange="changeStatusActive(' . $this->id . ', \'products/product\');"></input>
                <label data-off="' . Yii::t('app', 'Не') . '" data-on="' . Yii::t('app', 'Да') . '" for="check_' . $this->id . '"></label>
                <span></span>
            </label>';
    }
```

Comment: where do you bind the onchange event?

Comment: In the model part. ` ' onchange="changeStatusActive(' . $this->id . ', \'products/product\')`